# In Linux, remap keys from second keyboard to unicode characters and shortcuts

Tags: linux, keyboard, shortcuts, unicode, fluxbox

I would like to get a second keyboard for just frequently used unicode characters and keyboard shortcuts. Ie, I would like to bind the "a" key on my second keyboard to opening firefox, for example. Another example would be binding the "b" key to inserting the ✓ character, so I don't have to type the ctrl+shift+u, 2713 each time.

OS is Ubuntu, wm is fluxbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First find event handler of your second keyboard. Run

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
```

Find your second keyboard device in the output and note number of event handler. For example:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=6007 2900000 83802078 f040d001 feffffdf ffefffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7
```

"H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event2" tells us that device we want to monitor is /dev/input/event2. Now we need to capture pressed keys. A useful tool is `actkbd` - http://users.softlab.ece.ntua.gr/~thkala/projects/actkbd/ After downloading it and installing you can get keyboard codes with:

```
$ sudo actkbd -s -d /dev/input/event2
```

Pass event device you got before to `-d` option. Tap keys you want to use, note their numbers and turn off `actkbd` with <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut.

To bind commands to shorcturs put into actkbd configuration file, `/etc/actkbd.conf`, lines with following format: `key-numbers:::command` and run `actkbd` daemon again same way as before. For example to run `gedit` after tapping <kbd>a</kbd> key put this line:

```
30:::gedit
```

Inserting Unicode characters is more tricky. I don't know if there is a way to insert those directly but I can propose a simple workaround. You can use `xclip` or `xsel` command to put any string into clipboard, and then paste it into any application you want using middle mouse button. Example configuration line using <kbd>q</kbd> button key:

```
16:::echo -n '✓' | xsel
```